# The fundamental unit in the ring of algebraic integers. 1

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Suppose that there exists an element $r\in R$ with $r^n = 0$, for some $n \geq 1$. Prove that $1 - r$ is invertible. May I know how we can prove this theory with some examples?

Comment: This has been asked yesterday, I think. - Regarding examples, do you have any favorite ring with nilpotent elements? (And what is the relation of the title to the question?)

Comment: **Hint:** Do you know the sum of a full geometric progression?

Comment: **Hint:** $(1-r)(1+r)(1+r^2) \ldots (1+r^{2^{n-1}}) = (1-r^{2^n})$

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
   (1-r)(1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1}) &= 1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^{n-1} -r -r^2 - ... - r^{n-1} - r^n \\
   &= 1   
\end{align*}

Comment: Sir may get some written explanation as well

Comment: @ronil Therefore $1-r$ is invertible